# OpenLdap : How to query for alias objects from spring ldap api?

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I am using spring ldap to connect to OpenLdap.

Wondering if there is any way in which we can query all the aliases present inside a particular base? I tried ldaptemplate.search, but it returns only the object inside the base, according to the filter provided, and not the aliases associated with the objects.

Looking forward for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn off alias chasing via whatever API you are using. Then the result of the search is the alias objects themselves, not what they refer to.